# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'msg' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am implementing contact form with Spring Boot MVC and Thymeleaf.
I receive this error and exception, when open `/message`:

```
ERROR 8766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/message.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'msg' available as request attribute
```

My controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/message")
 public String message() {
        return "message";
 }
 @PostMapping("/message")
 public String sendMessage(@ModelAttribute(name = "msg") Message msg, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "main";
        }

        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);

        mailService.sendMessage(msg.getTitle(), msg.getMessage());

        return "message";
 }
```

message.html:

```
<form action="/message" th:action="@{/message}" th:object="${msg}" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Title:
            <input type="text" th:field="${msg.title}"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Message:
            <input type="text" th:field="${msg.message}"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

What is my mistake?
On the `/message` page error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/message.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/message.html]")
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
```

should be in your GetMapping, not where you have in the PostMapping. You Bind the Message object to the form in order to view the form;

```
@GetMapping("/message")
 public String message(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", new Message());
        return "message";
 }
```